# Export contacts from CRM to network folder ( IIS ) and show them on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, synchronization, crm, contacts

I would like to allow people to see ( not edit ) contacts from our CRM on their mobile devices. My idea was to export the contacts to .vcf file ( one single file with all contacts or more files ) and save them to IIS shared folder. These file(s) will be reguraly updated from our CRM ( every xx-hours ).

Will this work ? Can i just provide one URL (https://something.com/contacts) with user name & password ?

Comment: What did you try or investigate?

Comment: I was looking at CardDav, but didn't find how to use it directly with IIS. Everywhere was that it needs CardDav server like Radicale Or Baikal. Other way was using external cloud service ( for example owncloud ) or mail service ( Gmail or Yahoo ). But this way is also bit complicated - CRM -> Gmail -> mobile devices. My idea is CRM -> folder on IIS - mobile devices, because CRM and IIS are usually on the same computer.